# React state not updating when sent to child component as a handleSubmit function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update a searchResults state in dashboard.jsx.
My search form is in Header component, so I passed onSubmit function from Dashboard to Header.
onSubmit function contains state update.
The problem is that when I console log res, it shows the data that is receiving from spotify web api, but after I set the state using setState and console log it searchResults, it shows an empty array.
I am not sure why this is happening. When I go look up Chrome react dev tool, and browse the component, there is an array of objects that I got from API in the state.
Please HELP!!!

```js
const Dashboard = ({ code }) => {
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);
  const accessToken = useAuth(code);

  const onSubmit = (search) => {
    spotifyApi
      .searchTracks(search) //
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.body);
        setSearchResults(
          res.body.tracks.items.map((track) => {
            return {
              artist: track.artists[0].name,
              title: track.name,
              uri: track.uri,
              albumUrl: track.album.images[1],
            };
          })
        );
      });
  };
```

```js
const Header = ({ onSubmit }) => {
  const inputRef = useRef();
  const formRef = useRef();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let result = inputRef.current.value;
    formRef.current.reset();
    onSubmit(result);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles.header_left}>
        <h2>wMusic</h2>
      </div>
      <form ref={formRef} className={styles.header_mid} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          ref={inputRef}
          type='text'
          className={styles.search}
          placeholder='Search Songs/Artists'
        />
        <button type='submit' className={styles.search_button}>
          <BsSearch className={styles.search_icon} />
        </button>
      </form>

      <div className={styles.header_right}>
        <button className={styles.sign_out}>Sign Out</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

Comment: Hi, where are you rendering the searchResults?

Comment: the code looks good, maybe `res.body.tracks.items.map` fails, try outputting the result of it

Comment: <Header/> is child component of <Dashboard/>
I am sending onSubmit function as a prop to <Header/>